# Find nearby locations with google places

Tags: android, google-places, google-nearby

I am working with the new google places in Android API `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0` but Cannot to help the missing `Place picker`, because of this I have resorted to making my own place picker, I have been quite successful as seen in this picture.

[image: screenshot with place picker]

The issue I have is with the missing `APIs`, I would like to display nearby locations in the `bottomsheet` and been following [this tutorial](http://www.zoftino.com/current-location-and-nearby-places-android-example), in the tutorial they are using `GeoDataClient` and `PlaceDetectionClient` which are not part of the `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0` dependency, does anyone have an idea on the new implementation of `Nearby locations` with the new `places APIs`?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

I think that's your destination, using this api you can find nearbyplaces using the latlng and radius